# Manipulating a class by using subclasses

Tags: c++, inheritance, linked-list

In this template problem there is a user made linked list class named `List<T>` that does not have a method to remove its last element and we assume we cannot change it directly.

```
template<typename T>
class List {
public:
    class Iterator {
    public:
        T get_data() { 
            T to_be_returned = current->data;
            return to_be_returned;
        }
        void next_element() {
            current = current->next;
        }
        bool has_more_elements() {
            return current != NULL;
        }
    private:
       //...
    };
public:
    List();
    ~List();
    void print();
    void push_front(T x);
    void push_back(T x);
    Iterator get_iterator(); 
private:
   //...
};
```

Part one of this problem says create `MyList` a subclass of `List` and implement `remove_last()` there. I have written code below as solution but since it is a templates problem, am I missing something important about **templates** in this code?

```
template<typename T>
class MyList : public List<T>
{
public:
    void remove_last(List<T>& l)
    {
        typename MyList<T>::Iterator it = l.get_iterator();
        typename MyList<T>::Iterator it2 = it;

        if(!it.has_more_elements())
            return;

        this->push_back(it.get_data());
        it2.next_element();
        it.next_element();
        if(it.has_more_elements())
            it.next_element();
        else
            return MyList<T>::~MyList();

        while(it.has_more_elements())
        {
            this->push_back(it2.get_data());
            it2.next_element();
            it.next_element();
        }
    }
};
```

Next part of problem says assuming we need to remove last element only if it is a word with a lowercase first character, is it possible to implement this with templates? If not how can we solve it?

Comment: Isn't the `remove_last` function supposed to remove the last element from itself? Not reconstruct a passed in list...

Comment: @super Since I cannot change private members in `List`, what I do is create a `MyList` object and push_back all elements except last element of list into MyList...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your code.

First, if `List<T>` is to be inherited from, it needs to have

1. Either a `virtual` public destructor, or,
2. a non-`virtual` protected destructor.

Otherwise, any user code that refers to your `MyList<T>` object with a pointer/reference to `List<T>` will have memory leaks whenever they call the destructor for the corresponding object.

If you are not allowed to touch the provided `List<T>` code, you may inherit from it either via `protected` or `private` mechanism, to ensure that a pointer to `List<T>` will not be able to cause any trouble. But then, you need to remember that you would not be able to use the public API provided by `List<T>` when you are using `List<T>*` or `List<T>&`.

Then, you have another problem. In your question, you have mentioned that you are required to implement `remove_last()`. However, your signature in `MyList<T>::remove_last(List<T>& l)` does not match the requirement. I think, you should change the signature to fulfill this requirement.

Another problem I see in your code excerpt is that you are calling the destructor `MyList<T>::~MyList()` explicitly. This will have undefined behaviour in your application whenever the `else` condition is satisfied on the corresponding line. Think about the case

```cpp
/* some code */
{
  MyList<double> mylist;
  /* fill the list, do something with it */
  mylist.remove_last(); /* assuming you have changed the signature */
  /* assume you have hit the else statement as mentioned above */
  /* when leaving the scope, mylist will be destructed */
  /* double destruction problem */
}
/* some code */
```

See the comment, as provided in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)

> Note that calling a destructor directly for an ordinary object, such as a local variable, invokes undefined behavior when the destructor is called again, at the end of scope.

Finally, to answer your question, you should think of writing something along the lines:

```cpp
/* private inheritance to avoid possible leaks */
/* this means that List<T> is your implementation detail */
/* Then, you need to reveal the API of List<T> properly */
template <typename T> class MyList : private List<T> {
public:
  void remove_last() {
    auto it = List<T>::get_iterator();

    /* reach the last element by iterating through the list */
    while (it.has_more_elements())
      it.next_element();

    /* do something with the iterator, as you know that it has the last element
     * now */
  }
};
```

The code you have provided is not enough to give a concrete answer in this situation, as apparently, there is only `push_back` and `push_front` functionality provided by the iterator API of your `List<T>`. You need some public functionality on your `List<T>` or its iterator to be able to modify the underlying data. Moreover, please keep in mind that `it` as in my solution suggestion is *not* the actual data point; it is a sentinel used for the past-the-end iterator.

If you are sure there is no other public functionality available, you can create a `List<T>` and iterate through your variables while `push_back(...)`ing the values, until you reach the last element, as in:

```cpp
template <typename T> class MyList : private List<T> {
public:
  void remove_last() {
    List<T> temp;

    auto current = List<T>::get_iterator();
    auto prev{current};

    while (current.has_more_elements()) {
      prev = current;
      current.next_element();
      if (current.has_more_elements())
        temp.push_back(prev.get_data());
    }

    List<T>::operator=(std::move(temp)); /* call copy/move assignment */
  }
};
```

Final comments:

1. It is hard for me to check if my solution is actually working as intended, since you have not provided a [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example),
2. Please do *not* use `NULL`, as in this case it is most likely referring to a `nullptr`, which is the better thing to use.

**EDIT.** The only place where *I think* templates can come handy in this question is the application of some *predicate* function by the user. Think of the below modification, for instance:

```cpp
template <typename T> class MyList : private List<T> {
public:
  template <class Predicate> void remove_last(Predicate &&pred) {
    List<T> temp;

    auto current = List<T>::get_iterator();
    auto prev{current};

    while (current.has_more_elements()) {
      prev = current;
      current.next_element();
      if (current.has_more_elements()) {
        auto value = prev.get_data();
        if (pred(value))
          temp.push_back(std::move(value));
      }
    }

    List<T>::operator=(std::move(temp)); /* call copy/move assignment */
  }
  void remove_last() {
    remove_last([](const T &) { return true; });
  }
  void remove_last_if_word_lowercase() {
    remove_last([](const T &) {
      /* apply the *only if word and starts with lowercase logic */
      // return ...;
    });
  }
};
```

above, you avoid code duplication for predicates, and allow for compiler-side optimizations by using templated predicate functors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response. But doesn't inheriting from private break encapsulation? Also does inheriting from private allow me to directly access private members of `List`? You also said " you would not be able to use the public API provided by List<T>" but `Iterator` is public.. after inheriting will I be able to use it? Last question in your solution `while (current.has_more_elements())` How can I access elements of parent class in subclass without passing an object of `List` to `MyList`?

Comment: I do not know what you meant by breaking encapsulation, but you should have a look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class) reference to understand the differences between public, protected and private inheritance. No, private inheritance does _not_ allow for such an access. private members of a class are always private, and cannot be accessed any object but the classe's members and/or friends. Please read the reference... All your questions regarding member accesses to the parent are explained there.

Comment: "How can I access elements of parent class in subclass without passing an object of List to MyList" well, the subclass is also its parent, that's why you use inheritance. You can think of inheritance as getting composed of some other class (of course they are different things; but for this illustration, you can think of it like that). The subclass can refer to its portion/functionality that it inherits from, say, `Parent1`, by calling `Parent1::something`. You should read some material regarding derived classes.

Comment: Please check the final version of my answer, where, in the **EDIT** section, I have provided a templated `remove_last` member function.